# Latex, How to make algorithm span both columns in 2-column article

Tags: latex

I have algorithm pseudo code that is too wide for the 2-column format of my article. Given the basic algrithm below, is there a way to force it to span both columns?

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{CH election algorithm}
\label{CHalgorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{CH\textendash Election}{}
\For{each node $i$ \Pisymbol{psy}{206} $N$ }
\State Broadcast HELLO message to its neighbor
\State let $k$ \Pisymbol{psy}{206} $N1$ ($i$) U {$i$} be s.t
\State QOS($k$) = max {QOS($j$) \textbar $j$ \Pisymbol{psy}{206} $N1$($i$)  U $i$}
\State MPRSet($i$) = $k$
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 1):

This lists a couple of ways to switch to single-column layout from the two-column one. I don't know what you are using for your general layout so I cannot be any more specific.

I also don't know what algorithm's package you are using and so I don't know how these things work with it.  They do provide environments, within which you can set your algorithmic environments.

- Use [`multicol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=en) package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
% ... single-column format ...
\begin{multicols}{2}
% ... two columns ...
\end{multicols}
% ... back to single column ...
\end{document}
```

If you are getting your two columns via `\documentclass[twocolumn]` you may want to drop that, and provide two columns by the package, as shown above. Note that the package is `multicol` while the environemt is `multicols`.

- Use `widetext` package, via its [style file](https://svn.einsteintoolkit.org/documents/Paper_EinsteinToolkit_2010/widetext.sty). For this [`flushend`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/flushend?lang=en) package need be installed.

```latex
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
 \use{widetext}
 \begin{document}
 % two-column ...
 \begin{widetext}
 % one-column. Has horizontal lines to guide the eye.
 \end{widetext}
 % back to two columns
 \end{document}
```

**Note**   The `widetext` environment is available in many styles that are required (and provided) by journals, and in packages like `revtex`.  In which case you don't need the package, just use the environment.  Try it out, you may have that already.

Answer (score 0):

Some document classes offer a two-column mode for floats. For example, using `algorithm2e` with `revtex4-2`, one can use `begin{algorithm*}`

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

% ...

\begin{algorithm}
    behold my single-column alg
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm*}
    behold my double-column alg
\end{algorithm*}
```

A workaround in complicated situations where this doesn't work (as I sometimes experience) is to put the algorithm *inside* double-column `figure*`, using `H` to disable floating.

```latex
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        behold, my alg is still double column woo!
    \end{algorithm}
\end{figure*}
```

Just make sure you `\label` and `\caption` inside the inner `algorithm` environment!

Answer (score -4):

There are many ways to switch from double column format to single column format-

1. Use multicol package.
2. Use widetext package.
3. But, I generally used this

   \begin{figure*}

   Put your algorithm here

   \end{figure*}